# Chat.SE is down

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat

I get this when I open any page on Chat.SE:

[image]

Could this be fixed?

Comment: We are aware of the problem and are looking into it. Thanks.

Comment: "Could this be fixed?" - oh man, what's with the unreasonable demands today?

Comment: Were there too many chat flags?

Comment: I just then I accidentally the whole thing :(

Comment: I am most disappointed that we don't even get silly pictures to look at on the error page.

Comment: Feature request: Replace "500 Internal server error" with "Hey, this is a great opportunity for you to get out of the house for a couple of hours".

Comment: @Yannis - "Hey, this is a great opportunity for you to get out of the house for a couple of hours".

Comment: @Oded Well played ;) (Although I _am_ out of the house, I'm lucky enough to live in walking distance from the waterfront and numerous little coffee shops with great view of the sea. You won't really find me at home during the afternoon unless I'm sick or working late)

Comment: @Yannis - While here, it is snowing outside. That's English spring for you.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This was a DNS change gone wrong; it made `chat.stackexchange.com` point to the datacenter in New York instead of the (correct) Oregon datacenter, and New York doesn't know anything about that website.

This has been corrected; the broken DNS entry just has a TTL of 5 minutes, so if it's not already fixed for you (it is for me), it at least shouldn't be too long.

Comment: We don't really care what the problem was, just tell us who to blame.

Comment: It's awesome how bugs like this get fixed so fast that the system doesn't even let me accept this answer/bug fix yet :P Kudos to the team!

Comment: @balpha FYI, I also had an error page twice ("Don't worry, it's our fault" or something like that and: panda falling from the slide) when trying to log into chat, earlier today (a few hours ago).

Comment: Hey, should there be a Tavern outpost on http://chat.stackoverflow.com/, so if this happens again, we won't be caught with nowhere to go?

Comment: @Yannis It's alarming just how interchangeable 'who' and 'what' are in your comment. Good form sir, I salute.

Comment: @TimPost The [evidence](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/5815/some-cat-ate-the-whiteboard-chat-has-broke#comment15744_5815) suggest that Anna is to blame here.

Comment: except that TTL is often ignored by DNS caches, isn't it :( Still it'll almost certainly be fine for everyone within 48 hours :)

Comment: @JackDouglas Fortunately for those broken caches, chances are pretty good that they never got the wrong entry in the first place.

Comment: yes that's a good point, only a tiny minority of chat users will be cursing you for 48 hours ;)